# Django get_language_info_list in template is empty

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am making a website where the user can decide to view the website in either English or Dutch. I would like to do this with a dropdown menu, and for this I have added the following:

`settings.py`:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    ...
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'snvs/locale/'
]
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('nl', _('Nederlands'))
)
```

`urls.py` (main one)

```py
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path(_('admin') + '/', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    path(_('agenda') + '/', include('agenda.urls'), name='agenda'),
    path(_('winkel') + '/', include('store.urls'), name='store'),
)
```

my base template:

```html
              {% load i18n %}
              ...
              {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
              {% if languages|length > 1 %}
                <form action="{% url "set_language" %}" method="post" class="d-flex">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <select name="language" class="form-select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    {% for language in languages %}
                      <option value="{{ language.code }}"
                              {% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                        {{ language.name_local }}
                      </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                </form>
              {% endif %}
```

However the `LANGUAGES`, `languages` or `get_language_info_list` tag in the template always is an empty list, whereas it should return the LANGUAGES information as described in settings.py ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#get-language-info-list))

I know this same code worked for me before so I am at a loss ass to why this might be happening.

This is what the end result should look like (working on a previous website):

[image]

And showing the `{{ languages }}` tag:

[image]

I have tried to determine the difference between either website settings.py and the new one but I can't find it (willing to upload both sources completely if necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add the `django.template.context_processors.i18n` context processor in `settings.py`